# How to turn off 1 of 2 monitors in c++ linux?//

Tags: c++, linux, monitor

How to turn off 1 of 2 monitors c++? I tried used DPMS library, but they turn off all monitors.

```
dpy = XOpenDisplay(0);
DPMSEnable(dpy);
DPMSForceLevel(dpy, DPMSModeOff);
XSync(dpy, False);
```